# Install scripts on deployments

Tags: install-script, deployment

Is there a way to force the install scripts to run for every new deployment? When I deploy a new git branch to our QA servers, the install scripts are not kicking off since magento thinks they already ran. I can fix it manually by removing the necessary rows from the core_resource table and refresh the page. I would like to be able to do this programmatically as a part of our deployment process without specifying core_resource rows that can be added or changed by our developers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using versioning system so whenever you deploy you should create upgrade script and increase your version of module that will automatically re-run sql scripts and no need any change in `core_resource`.

**For First deployment of same module**

Your first module file in `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml` will lool like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Next you have to define same version at `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/config.xml` will look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
```

And setup script should look like `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/module_setup/install-1.0.0.php` will look like.

```
<?php  
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

//Your sql script

$installer->endSetup();
```

**For Next deployment of same module**

Your module file in `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml` will lool like. Increased version.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Next you have to update version in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/config.xml` will look like. Increased version.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
```

And setup script should look like `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/module_setup/upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php` will look like. I have just changed setup script name that `upgrade-{Previous version}-{New version}.php` it will recognize by magento and it will run sql script without changing in `core_resource` table

```
<?php  
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

//Your sql script

$installer->endSetup();
```